# save bullet list on RichTextBox to XML

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, richtextbox

This is my issue
I want to save bullet style on RichTextBox on VS2010 to XML File. 
When I create content, it's ok. But when I save it. The bullet is missing. It's just have plain text. 
Please help me to save actually content of RichTextBox in XML File, or maybe just file.txt

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code

```
richTextBox1.SelectionBullet = true;
```

You can encapsulate in your restitution

```
<ol>
 <li>returned data</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's just enable/disable bullet style of TextRich Box. My issue is when i save it to file.txt, It's missing bullet, it just plain text

Comment: How can I save .txt like that:                                             
    . Option1                              
    . Option2

Comment: you create your stream and you save with streamwriter

Answer (score 0):

A plain .TXT file isn't enough, you need to save the file using the .RTF extension (Rich Text Format).

Please call:

```
  //File path must have .RTF at the end
  richTextBox1.SaveFile(filePath);
```

Ensure your extension is .RTF and you will be able to save the formatted rich text box :)